# LEFT OUTER JOIN conditions for two queries?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have the following two queries to find pageviews and orders for each week starting from Jan 2014.

```
select productid,
EXTRACT (week from dt)as WEEK,
count(productid)as PageViews
from PageView
where client = 'XYZ'
and dt between '2014-06-01' and '2014-06-30'
GROUP BY WEEK, productid
ORDER BY WEEK asc;
```

and

```
select
count(distinct t.orderid),
EXTRACT(week from t.dt) AS WEEK
FROM Transaction t
where t.client = 'XYZ'
and t.dt between '2014-01-01' AND '2014-06-30'
GROUP BY WEEK
ORDER BY WEEK asc;
```

In order to get the correct data, I need to create a condition on join which matched the week from Transaction and PageView Tables , something like Week from Transaction = Week from PageView. I however have no clue of what the syntax for this would be like .

Doing a simple

```
PageView pv LEFT OUTER JOIN Transaction t
ON pv.productid = t.productid 
AND EXTRACT(week from t.dt) = EXTRACT(week from pv.dt)
```

does not give a correct output (i.e. the pageviews and Orders are coming significantly high). Can someone please shed some light on how to combine these two queries two get a desired output which is all the products from PageView table and corresponding Orders from the Transaction table grouped by week

Comment: do pageview and trans table have any relation between them?

Comment: What are the Primary Keys for both tables? What Alternate Keys (if any) exist for both tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select week, pid, pageviews, orders
from
    (
        select
            date_trunc('week', dt) as week,
            productid as pid,
            count(productid) as pageviews
        from pageview
        where client = 'XYZ' and dt between '2014-06-01' and '2014-06-30'
        group by 1, 2
    ) pv
    full outer join
    (
        select
            date_trunc('week', dt) as week,
            product_id as pid,
            count(orderid) as orders
        from transaction
        where client = 'XYZ' and dt between '2014-01-01' and '2014-06-30'
        group by 1, 2
    ) t using (week, pid)
order by 1, 2
```

Comment: Why a `full outer join`? Just trying to understand.

Comment: @Rahul Is it possible to have orders without views for a certain product id? It is not clear in the question. If the answer is no then just change `full outer` to `left` although the `full` will work correctly, just with the risk of the planer not finding the best plan.

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto Thank you , that seems to work quite well . However the date_trunc gives a complete date with timestamp than just the week number. I guess I should have mentioned that in the question . IS EXTRACT(week from dt) as WEEK a better option ?

Comment: @AshwinSingh extract(week) will be wrong for periods about or longer than one year. And will sort incorrectly for periods involving the new year. Otherwise it is fine

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto Just one more thing, if I want to run this query for n number of Clients, do I just add select client_name in both the select statements ?

Comment: @AshwinSingh Is the client_id in both tables? How do you want the grouping? client -> week -> pid? week -> client -> pid? Another one? Open another question referring to this one preferably with the schema.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is `ON pv.productid = t.productid AND EXTRACT(week from t.dt) = EXTRACT(week from pv.dt)`

This can't be on the left join.  ID's between PV and T may match but the weeks may be null in some cases. so an AND would eliminate the left join.

So you just have to join on the ID's first so you have the resulting Cartesian.  Then you need to filter out the non-matching weeks but leave in the T.Null values..  However it assumes that t.dt can't be null if it can be null the counts may still be off depending on how you want to handle nulls in the transaction table date.

Additionally you may need to use inline views (but I think this is overkill)

```
SELECT * 
FROM
(select productid,
  EXTRACT (week from dt)as WEEK,
  count(productid)as PageViews
  from PageView
  where client = 'XYZ'
  and dt between '2014-06-01' and '2014-06-30'
  GROUP BY WEEK, productid) PV
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT
  count(distinct t.orderid),
  EXTRACT(week from t.dt) AS WEEK
  FROM Transaction t
  where t.client = 'XYZ'
  and t.dt between '2014-01-01' AND '2014-06-30'
  GROUP BY WEEK) T
ON pv.productid = t.productid  --The gold is in this and the next line
WHERE (T.Week = PV.Week OR T.Week is null)  --don't forget this one.
```

I don't think this will work...
ON (PV.ProductID=T.productID and T.Week=PV.Week) 
 OR (PV.ProductID = T.ProductID AND T.Week is null)

because T.Week will not have been evaluated yet as the Cartesian will not have been generated. thus why I think it belongs in the where.

Comment: Presumably the tables must also join on either Customer ID or Order ID?

Comment: Yep, exactly but I think you should remove that `PV.Week = T.Week`

Comment: Not sure why did you removed your query? It was correct per me.

Comment: That makes it an inner join ! I tried that but it eliminates some of the products that exist only in the PageView Table.

Comment: I think you want the where clause.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your inputs :)

Comment: @Rahul because I really don't think it helps.  The ON and the where clause and I believe address the problem.

Comment: Not sure but with my comment I meant the idea of inner view. I was actually posting that as answer but then removed seeing that you already have answered that. Again, the condition `AND EXTRACT(week from t.dt) = EXTRACT(week from pv.dt)` don't make any sense to me. I would say just joining on `pv.productid = t.productid` would be sufficient but can't assure that though.